# CS5211AGP wireless RF transmitter (433MHZ) address decoding problem

Tags: wireless

I am using CS5211AGP wireless RF transmitter to transmit some data and another side receive this data through nRf905 as receiver. But now problem is how can I decode RF transmitter address (because transmitter and receiver address must be same).

if any one working on this module then please suggest me how can I decode address.

Please show below image where you can see the connection of address and zone.[image]

[image]

Now please say about what address should I set at receiver side for communication.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
rajneesh

Comment: I don't think the nRf905 and CS5211AGP are compatible. They both use their own protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at mine, wich address is 01212012, acording to a sticker in a side. I can see in mine jumpers as follows (starting from A0): -HLHL-HL-H-H where - means no jumper. Based on my sticker I can see that 0 is equivalent to NO-JUMPER, 1 is H and 2 is L. By watching yours I can tell that your code is 21111002.
The other 4 jumpers is what I don-t understand, but if I change any of them, my alarm no longer detects any change.
Hope this helps...
Regards.